# F# SQL data access best practices

Tags: f#, functional-programming, repository

I started to learn F# some weeks ago. I come from a C# and imperative langages background.
Usually, in imperative langages, is comon to see the 3 layers (Controllers, Services and Repositories) in a entreprise application. 
Clearly, this is not a functional design. With the CRUD operations that are performed over DTO objects.

I would like to know how to implement/architecture such application in a "pure" functional way in F#.

I put "pure" in parentesis as I'm not looking into the IO monad at this stage. But following some best practices:

- Dont have mutable states
- Dont use inheritance or interfaces/abstract classes
- Use pattern matching as much of possible
- Separate IO interaction as much as possible from the logic

Have you ever developed such a project in F# in your company and how did you organize your project (modules/functions)?

Also, which API or library did you use (mainly for the Database access)?

Thanks a lot

Comment: If you are in Windows/MSSQL server universe then the best data access library is a SqlClient type provider:  http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data.SqlClient/

Comment: I am, we use sql server as database